# How to change image src that contain Parent tags using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, regex

How do I change image src that contain Parent tags using jquery?

Can you please tell how to retrieve the same using c#?

C# code:

```
    string s;

    s= "<span id=\"span1\"><table><tr><td><img src=\"/image/img01.jpg\"></td></tr>";
    I have formatted above code to string and assigned to one label 

    label1.text=s.tostring();
```

Now i want to change the img src using jquery.

I'm new to jquery please any one help me to solve this.
* Note: i dont want to use id attribute for img tag.

Comment: Does label1 display string or html? Do you want to change from string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two simple option, firstly use the code which given by "andy"

```
$('#span1 img').attr('src','img02.jpg');
```

or

```
<img src=\"/image/img01.jpg\" id="exampleimg">

$('#exampleimg').attr('src','img02.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

provided you only have one image inside the span (like your example):

```
$('#span1 img').attr('src','img02.jpg');
```

Comment: Can u please tell how to retrieve the same using c#

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#span1 img').attr('src', '/path/to/new/img.jpg');
```

That should do the trick for you.

edit - beaten to the punch by 2 mins!

Comment: Can u please tell how to retrieve the same using c#